# Can't post comment to blog in wp-multisite

Tags: comments

I'm running a wp-multisite install with ~100 blogs. I recently discovered a blog that I can't post a comment to (though I've been able to previously). When I try to submit a comment, I get the following warning dialog: 
[image]

When I press send "send" I get an the comment field looks like this:

[image]

And nothing ever happens. I'm able to post comments to other blogs on the wp-multisite without problems, and this happens even when I'm logged in as superadmin.

Comment: Could you provide link to live example? What theme are you using or what is code, used to output comment form in it?

Comment: Here's the link to the blog: https://wordpress.standrews-de.org/uamakiri/2013/11/13/capstone-spring-constant-part-2/

Comment: You seem to be using Jetpack for comments, have you tried disabling it? If plugin is the issue this might be better aimed at its developers.

Comment: Yes. When I turned off Jetpack, the comment system began to work again. I'll check with its developers.